# How do you prevent users from directly messaging a Discord bot that you created on your own?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I've created a discord bot using node.js and I'm having troubles with users spamming messages to my chat bot's DM. Any help would be great!

Answer (score 1):

At the top of your `message` event put:

```js
// If the message is sent in dm
if (message.channel.type === 'dm') return;
```